# List in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I am new to Visual Basic, and I need help.

I have previously used Python where you simply create a list of items by simply doing:

> list = [item1, item2]

But I have no idea how I can do this in Visual Basic.

Please can someone help me to simply create a list, like you can in Python, but in Visual Basic?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/

Comment: Are search engines disabled in your locale? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=VB.NET+List&oq=VB.NET+List&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j5j69i65l2j69i60.2208j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 returns, among other things, https://www.dotnetperls.com/list-vbnet which has some really very clear examples. Equally you could use arrays if you want a simpler structure. Did you research or try _anything_ before posting?

Comment: Great @ADyson, I love this page! :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
dim list as item() = {item1, item2}
```

The () next to item signify that it is an array.

A working example of an integer list:

```
Dim list As Integer() = {1, 2, 3}
```

These lists are refered to as "arrays" though.

If you want an actual list, you can do:

```
Dim list As New List(Of Integer)({1,2,3})
```

This one allows you to access .Add and .AddRange, and does not hold a static capacity.

Answer (score 2):

```
  Dim arraylist As New ArrayList
  arraylist.Add("item")
```

You can use this. It's a dynamic list

Answer (score 0):

A list in Python would essentially be an Array in Visual Basic.

You would do this by saying `Dim list(x) As Integer` and then adding either the size of the list (in the parenthesis) or using a `ReDim` statement to create a dynamic array if you do not know what the initial size of the array is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you need it for, you could try creating a new data structure and then giving it properties that you desire. I also started on python and moved into visual basic and had a similar issue. Interestingly, I found that sometimes it is better to create a data structure over a list.

for example, here is a piece of code which I wrote creating a structure called 'singularity' which has some properties (I would have previously made this into a list or an array):

Public Class singularity

```
Public ReadOnly Property Mass As Single

Public Property Center As New Vector2(600, 600)
Public Property Velocity As Vector2

Public Sub New()

    Mass = 1000

End Sub
```

I can then create an instance of this at any point I want and call on these properties. If I was to require the properties to change I can do that also!

I hope this gives you more insight and helps, I know others answered your question directly but I thought I'd give a bit more insight! :)

Comment: *I just saw that this is an old question, but this may be insightful to others in the future :)